# opencart 2.0.1.0 payment error with paypal when ordering 1 item

Tags: php, paypal, checkout, shopping-cart, opencart2.x

We have a opencart 2.0.1.0 setup for over 2 years. Our client report a problem with paypal standard processing at checkout. This has only occurred in the past couple of weeks, it has been working without error before the 28th march.

when the order is processing it goes to Paypal and we get the following error:
'Things don't appear to be working at the moment. Please try again later.'

the url for this page is:
https://www.paypal.com/webapps/shoppingcart/error?flowlogging_id=68742a854b13a&code=ADDRESS_ERROR&mfid=1491730428804_3441ea66ee65a

There are no errors in the error logs in opencart or in the server logs.

The checkout has a onestep check module installed with guest checkout only, there is no shipping or taxes applied.

I have tried all kinds of product variations, including removing options, required fields, etc and always get the same error as the clients and their customers get.

As PayPal was the only payment method, I turned on 'Cash On Delivery' option and the orders process as they should so the problem is with Paypal.

I have checked all settings incase the client has changed something without realizing but everything appears to be ok.

I then ordered 2 products and it worked, the Paypal page loaded with the paypal guest login page with all the correct details.

I tried several combinations of orders including ordering 2 units of one product. This time the payment error with paypal occurred again.

So if I order 2 products it works as it should. There is no minimum order total option in opencart so this isn't causing a problem.

As everything was working ok previously, and i cant find any errors in the cart ordering I am at a lost as to why this is happening. Can anyone help please, I have lodge a t ticket with paypal but it will take from 24-48hrs for their reply.

Answer (score 0):

I am having the same issue. Have a look at the following. I think it may be due to a PayPal update done on March 31st

https://www.antropy.co.uk/blog/opencart-paypal-standard-error-after-march-31st-2017-update/